# When adding new project to VS solution it messes up solution dependencies

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dependencies

We have huge project solution with about 20 projects and 6 different build configurations. Each build configuration has own dependencies, when adding new project to the solution, it changes other projects dependencies and fails to compile. Any ideas on how to add new project without causing any affect to other projects and it's dependencies?

Thanks.

Comment: I remember when 20 projects seemed huge... Is the project that you're adding have the same name or GUID as any other projects currently in your solution? Does it have its own dependencies to other projects already loaded in your solution? Do existing projects in your solution have a dependency to the new one you're adding?

Comment: IME, Build Order pretty much works itself out when all the projects are in the same solution.  However, it's tricky when they are not all part of the same solution.  You can configure build order in the solution properties.  I would start by diagramming your dependencies with a tool like NDepend.  Identify circular references etc...Then post the diagram if you still feel stuck.

Comment: Does it really change the references, or just creates a new solution-level configuration in which some projects are excluded from build?

Comment: it doesn't creates new solution-level configuration but it reorders project build order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps of solving the problem:

1. Remove added project from the solution
2. Revert solution file to     its original state
3. Open recently added project .csproj file in the    notepad++ and open .csproj file
   of any project that's been already in    solution.
4. Compare all the    properties between two files and make       sure
   they have the same    Build Configurations, Configurations,
   Platform, Platform    target. (Just take all this info from your old
   project)
5. Save your new project's .csproj file and right click on     your
   solution in visual studio and add existing project which will be
   the project you want to add.

Result: Visual studio doesn't touches solution dependencies.